# Background Images in Blender Will not show

Tags: image

I'm unable to display images as background images in Blender.

I've tried it as a jpeg and a png.

I have opacity set to 1. I've tried scaling the size from 1-1000. I've tried looking at every view available. Nothing seems to work.

[image: Sceen shot of my settings with Front and Left views]

Comment: Images does not show in perspective mode.  Turn on Orthographic mode by pressing Numpad 5, and you should see them.

Comment: This gets asked quite oftten. Background images work only in **Camera Perspective** view,  or any of the **Preset Ortho** views (Top, Bottom, Left, Right, Front or Back)

Answer (score 0):

As TeaCrab mentioned in comment, it was because I was in perspective mode. Thank you.